# Dashboard not displaying the Months in a proper manner

Tags: dashboard

[image: Dashboard]

Hi,

I have created a formula field which displays Months in Text. The idea behind this was to create a report for the case object, where it gives the report of cases opened in Months. I got the reports and dashboards pulled up with the accurate data. But, if you notice the picture, the table is sorted by the case counts and not by months. Is there a possibility to sort the months accordingly like Jan to Dec and not jumbled up as in the picture.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note on how these dashboards render and sort is based on how your report is sorted

Suggestion to do the following

1)Include the number field only and group by number field and sort it by the number and this would be in order

2)Sorting of report based on formula field not possible and that's the other hurdle yow will face if you make a formula field

3)Use workflow and in text field instead of January,febraruary use something like 1 Jan,2 Feb,3 march and that would allow you to sort and hence report will be sorted .

4)How about buketting 1 as JAN,2 as FEB etc and then sorting on month and using the report for dashboard should also display JAN,FEB etc in your dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to sort it out.

Rename the month name by appending month number as prefix.
For example, "01 January", "02 February"

Comment: This answer would be better if you went into detail about _what_ the problem is, and _how_ this approach resolves it. It's also very similar to the existing answer which was given 6 years ago.