# How to display months in order wise in dashboard? Ex: Jan, Feb, Mar

Tags: dashboard

I would like to display month in order wise in dashboard.
Ex: Jan, Feb, Mar...Dec.

Can any one suggest a way please?
Please find below image for reference. I am getting in Alphabetic order. I need to display in Months order like Jan, Feb...
[image]

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17557/dashboard-not-displaying-the-months-in-a-proper-manner Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to group rows by whatever date field you need to group. Once Group by row is done then apply sort by Calendar Month option for that particular field. Please go to the below link once it might help you.
[Create a Growth Report in Salesforce Lightning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2YTU-NS7fE)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Its working